# How to display a nested collection with .ps1xml file in powershell

Tags: powershell, format

I have a hierarchical object structure like this:

```
public class Department
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public Employee[] Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Speciallity { get; set; }
}
```

How can i create a custom .ps1xml file that will let me display `Department(s)` as follows:

> ```
>     Department : Testers
>     Manager    : P.H. Boss
>
> Name                       Speciallity
> ----------                 -----------------------------
> Some Employee              .Net
> Another Employee           BizTalk
> Yet Another                PowerShell
> ...                        ...
>
>
>     Department : Developers
>     Manager    : Wally
>
> Name                       Speciallity
> ----------                 -----------------------------
> Some Employee              .Net
> Another Employee           BizTalk
> Yet Another                PowerShell
> ...                        ...
> ```

The main problem i'm having is how i can define a `<View>` item that is selected for a `Department`, that is based on a `TableControl`, but which displays the `Department.Employees` in the table control.

I can display `Employee`(s) perfectly fine using a `View`:

```
<View>
    <Name>Employee</Name>
    <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>Employee</TypeName>
    </ViewSelectedBy>
   <TableControl>
        <TableHeaders>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Label>Name</Label>
                <Width>30</Width>
            </TableColumnHeader>
            <TableColumnHeader>
                <Label>Speciallity</Label>
                <Width>50</Width>
            </TableColumnHeader>
        </TableHeaders>
        <TableRowEntries>
            <TableRowEntry>
                <Wrap/>
                <TableColumnItems>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                    <TableColumnItem>
                        <PropertyName>Speciallity</PropertyName>
                    </TableColumnItem>
                </TableColumnItems>
            </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
    </TableControl>
</View>
```

And i can format departments using a list format:

```
<View>
    <Name>TestResultSet</Name>
    <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>Department</TypeName>
    </ViewSelectedBy>
    <ListControl>
        <ListEntries>
            <ListEntry>
                <ListItems>
                    <ListItem>
                        <Label>Department</Label>
                        <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
                    </ListItem>
                    <ListItem>
                        <PropertyName>Manager</PropertyName>
                    </ListItem>
                </ListItems>
            </ListEntry>
        </ListEntries>
    </ListControl>
</View>
```

But how do i add a table of the employees after the department?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display nested objects with .ps1xml file through c# cmdlet into powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102864/how-to-display-nested-objects-with-ps1xml-file-through-c-sharp-cmdlet-into-powe)

Comment: @GrahamGold : I noticed that question, but is does not deal with a nested `collection`. I think the difference is important enough to justify a seperate question. I did copy some sample code from that question though :-)

Comment: I ended up adding a PSParentPath NoteProperty to the repeating items, and grouping the output on that field. There seems to be no better way. I will update here with some demo code for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to make use of  `<GroupBy>...</GroupBy`  and also `<Control><CustomControl>...</CustomControl></Control>`

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/perpetual-motion/discutils/blob/master/utils/DiscUtils.PowerShell/DiscUtils.Format.ps1xml) ps1xml format file for DiscUtils module, haven't had the chance to play with it myself yet but it may put you on the right path.

See also the `help about_Format.ps1xml` which has some info, though a little light on examples for some aspects.

Comment: I solved this with the `<GroupBy>` construct, but i had to add a `PSParentPath` NoteProperty to my Employee object to make this work. I'm guessing there is no other way to achieve this.