# Display Nested Array in PS1XML

Tags: powershell, formatting, format, transformation

I've got a function that returns a PSCustomObject that contains 3 properties:  string, array1, array2.  The human consumable information solely exists within array1.  That array has four properties each with string values.  My PS1XML has a scriptblock that tries to do $_.Array1, but that doesn't expand the array (doesn't return anything).  Doing a `Select -Expand` isn't functional either.

Is there some method of displaying the nested array while maintaining the parent object structure?

Comment: You may use ConvertTo-Json to display the object in a structured way.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ - You solved this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776048/how-to-display-a-nested-collection-with-ps1xml-file-in-powershell).  Happen to be able to pull out an example of how you utilized `PSParentPath` that I could look at?  I'm missing the ball on how you got the nested collection out.  Thank you.